# Comma between two values in a macro

Tags: c, u8glib

I am working on a project involving an Aduino and screen.

As i was going through the [u8glib (Arduino Monochrome Graphics Library for LCDs and OLEDs)](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib), something caught my attention:

```
#define U8G_ESC_DLY(x) 255, ((x) & 0x7f)
#define U8G_ESC_CS(x) 255, (0xd0 | ((x)&0x0f))
```

How can i interpret this macro for a given x value ?

Comment: Macro's aren't really code. They just work on the plain text. Just look at them as if they are a "find and replace" function in a text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i interpret this macro for a given x value ?

As normal. First expand the macro, and *then* worry about what the comma means in context. In an expression the result is the expression on the right of the comma. In a function call it stands in for two arguments. Just look at where it's used and that's what it will mean.

Comment: U8G_ESC_DLY(10),              /* delay 10 ms */  

so in a concept like this, i can omit the left side of the comma.But can you elaborate on the function call part ? How can you define a function like this in the first place ?

Comment: `somefunctionthattakestwoargs(SOMEMACROWITHACOMMA)`

Comment: The library uses that to create a list of commands to initialize the display. [See where it is used](https://github.com/olikraus/u8glib/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=U8G_ESC_CS). As you can see, they store an array of commands that have to be send to initialize. So in this case, send `255` and then send the last x (with the first bit set to zero).